# Напишите функцию, которая возвращает новый объект без указанных значений

Tags: javascript

Задание: Напишите функцию, которая возвращает новый объект без указанных значений

Что получилось у меня:

```
function without(object, objectKey) {
    for (prop in object) {
        if (object[prop] === objectKey) delete object[prop]
    }
    return object
}
```

Проблема: Как сделать так, чтобы ПРИ ВЫЗОВЕ ФУНКЦИИ в аргументах можно было указывать несколько ключей, например: `console.log(without(user, user.height, user.age,...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант передавать второй аргумент в виде массива со свойствами, которые нужно удалить, и внутри перебирать его элементы

```js
let user = {
  age: 18,
  height:180,
  size: 25,
};

function without(object, objectKey) {
    for (prop in object) {
        if (objectKey.find((el) => el === prop)) delete object[prop]
    }
    return object
}

console.log(without(user, ['age', 'height']));
```

Либо то же самое, но с передачей аргументов по одному

```js
let user = {
  age: 18,
  height:180,
  size: 25,
};

function without(object, ...objectKey) {
    for (prop in object) {
        if (objectKey.find((el) => el === prop)) delete object[prop]
    }
    return object
}

console.log(without(user, 'age', 'height'));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а есть вариант не использовать массив и его методы?

Comment: @Socome, так или иначе, если вы работаете с произвольным количеством аргументов, которые нужно передать в функцию, без массивов не обойтись. Как следствие, без их методов тоже не обойтись. Либо вы передаете в функцию массив, либо вы передаете по одному аргументу, а в самой функции принимаете остаточные аргументы в виде массива. Другого способа на ум не приходит.